# Unset session within echo causing issues

Tags: php

I am getting the following error and can not figure out why. I've been staring at this for too long..

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_UNSET in blah/blah/blah
```

My code:

Essentially, I am trying to give the user the ability to clear a session via clicking a link.  Not sure where I am going wrong within my syntax... Any help would be much appreciated!

NOTE: Yes, my code is within php blocks

```
echo "<span><a href='" . unset($_SESSION['vertical']) . "'>clear "
 . $vertical . "</a></span>";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not going to work - you need to call a link to a PHP page that does the unset. If nothing else - that would call `unset` when the link was generated, rather than when it was clicked.

Comment: @andrewsi I believe calling another page as you suggest will interrupt the users experience.  Basically, I am using session variables to store information that will help filter search results.  I am trying to allow the visitor to kill that session variable if they decide they don't want a particular filter applied any more.  I believe if I link to another page, the visitor will need to start their search and apply filters all over again...

Comment: Have a look at the answer from m_poorUser - you need to use AJAX, in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call PHP functions after the page has finished loading. PHP is a server-side technology and works on the server, not on the client's computer. Which means, you won't be able to call a PHP function without sending the details to the script.

If you're trying to trigger the `unset` function when the user clicks the link, then you could create a link to a script where you unset the `$_SESSION` variable:

```
<span><a href='somepage.php?somevar=42'>foo</a></span>
```

When the user clicks on the link, they'll be taken to `somepage.php`. Now, you can check if the `somevar` key is set and then `unset` the session in the script:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['somevar'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['vertical']);
}
```

If you want to do this without a page refresh, then you might want to take a look at [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

When you write `unset($_SESSION['x'])` x in session will be deleted. It will executed immediately. You should give a link to a page that will do the unsetting.

If you want to clear a session variable in same page you need to make an AJAX call to another page which has the code `unset($_SESSION['x'])`.

Comment: I want it executed immediately.  I'm developing a filtering system and would like the user to be able to drop any of their filters at any time.  If I link to another php page that unsets the session, their current experience will be interrupted, which I don't want... any thoughts?

Comment: @user2828701: See the last part of my answer.

Comment: You do NOT want to execute it immediately. You want to execute it when link clicked. When I say immediately, what I meant is when page done loading it will be already executed. You need to use Javascript if you don2t want to reload the page. Search for "PHP AJAX call example/tutorial". There are plenty of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
<a href="sessiondestroy.php">Clear " . $vertical . "</a>
```

And in clearsession.php write:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['vertical']);
?>
```