# How to call a PHP function with parameter call with OnClick event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to call a PHP function as simply as possible with `OnClick` event:

```
<button onclick="Function(5)">Call PHP function</button>
```

I searched for the answer, but could not find it. I think I have to use AJAX or something, but I have no experience with it. Please give me an example as simple as possible on how to call a PHP function with parameter using `OnClick` event.

Comment: Yes, you will need ajax. Here's jquerys documentation on sending a request with their library. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/

Comment: Look at the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button

Comment: But why onclick? Why not onmouseclick?

Comment: @Cristik onmouseclick is ok too

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use inline events on html elements - it becomes a bit of a mess. You are going to need to use Ajax to get this done. Firstly i would set up your php function in it's own page/action then set up your javascript/jquery request event like so.

```
<button class="call-php" value="click me"/>

$('.call-php').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url  : '/myphp.php', 
            type : 'get',
            data : {},
            success:function(data) {
                // do something
            }, 
        });
});
```

Comment: @Niloct What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can call like this

```
<?php Function(5)?>)
```