# how to use usb trigger for cash drawer in website programmer

Tags: javascript, php, usb

I have a question, how to open cash drawer using USB trigger for cash drawer (BT-100U). Does anyone have advice how to use it in website?

Its is the description fro the product.
Description : BT-100U Cash Drawer Driver Trigger With USB Interface BT-100U cash drawer trigger is designed to provide USB interfacing to the cash drawer. This allows the cash drawer- which is previously connected to POS printer or cash register- to be directly connected to a USB port of the computer. This means through the USB Trigger the cash drawer can be directly connected to the computer when this no printer used in the POS system. The BT-100U USB trigger module uses a virtual serial port driver- making it appear to software like a standard RS232 serial port. This way existing POS software can communicate with the USB cash drawer trigger as though connected to a serial port. A unique serial number is assigned to each USB trigger module and driver software will assign the next available serial port to each device it recognizes(multiple triggers can be used on one computer). Cash drawer can be directly connected to the computer with BT-100U Powered by USB bus- external power is not required Allows for "Hot Plugging"- plug and play connectivity No need to set the COM property Suitable to any cash drawer command.

please explain to me with example code. Thank you.

Comment: and what have you **tried yourself** so far? anything? or do you want us to do your job *for* you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the website runs on a server on which `php` is installed (*php is server side*) on the other end is the browser in that `javascript runs`  (*javascript is client side*).

**server side**

the cash drawer is attached to the server so you can control the cash drawer using *php* with `RS-232` commands. the cash drawer enumerates as a Virtual COM port on the server machine. you have to to nothing more, just plug it in and the server OS will establish the virtual COM port (if the driver is installed). There is a library to send RS-232 commands named *PHP Direct IO*, see http://www.brainboxes.com/faq/items/how-do-i-control-a-serial-port-using-php

a virtual com port is USB CDC ACM class if you have to install driver

**link to client side**

as a link you can use an `ajax request` that the browser sends to the server. when this request is processed it triggers the PHP function that sends the Rs-232 commands to the cash drawer.
as example see http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function and http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/592009/javascript-interface-with-rs-232-serial-port

**client side**

on client side you can choose a button or another html element you like and connect the ajax request with it using jquery, javascript,... when the button/element is clicked it sends the ajax request to the server what triggers the php function that sends the RS-232 command to the BT

see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function