# Click and send mail to user using A-Frame and php

Tags: php, html, aframe

I want to send email by clicking on button using aframe. I did something but that does not work. Here is working flow.
I have database and I am getting user email form database.
Here is html:

```
<a-plane id="information-button" name="button-press" class="clickable" 
 position="6 -4.845 3" rotation="0 -30 0" width="3" height="1" color="#000">
      <a-text value="More Info" position="-0.946 0.077 0.349" scale="2 2 2"> 
      </a-text>
</a-plane>
```

Here is email.php to send the email.

```
<?php 
include('server.php');
session_start();
?>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['button-press'])) {
require "PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/OAuth.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/POP3.php";
require "PHPMailer/src/Exception.php";
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

if (isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . '\r\n';
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n'; 
    $message = '<p><strong>You are in.</strong></p>';
    $subj = 'More Information';
    $to = 'falak@oddly.co';
    $from = 'falaksabbir3@gmail.com';

define('GUSER', 'falaksabbir3@gmail.com'); // GMail username
define('GPWD', '******');
define('SMTPUSER', 'falaksabbir3@gmail.com'); // sec. smtp username
define('SMTPPWD', '******'); // sec. password
define('SMTPSERVER', 'smtp.gmail.com'); // sec. smtp server



//send mail

if ( smtpmailer($to, $from, $name, $subj, $message,$headers)){
        echo 'Message send via Gmail';
    } else {
        if (!smtpmailer($to, $from, $name, $subj, $message,$headers)){
            if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
        } else {
            echo 'Yep, the message is send (after doing some hard work)';
        }
    }

//send email function

function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body, $is_gmail = true) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    if ($is_gmail) {
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
        $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->Port = 465;  
        $mail->Username = GUSER;  
        $mail->Password = GPWD;   
    } 
    else {
        $mail->Host = SMTPSERVER;
        $mail->Username = SMTPUSER;  
        $mail->Password = SMTPPWD;
    }        
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->IsHTML(true); 
    $mail->AddAddress($to); 
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
}}
?>
```

So this is how I did. Can I do php with aframe? Or any guidelines with this.

Comment: never share your details like password..

Comment: Yes sorry.And thank you.

Comment: why not? It will be usefull :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do PHP with A-Frame.

Currently though your A-Frame code does not interact with your PHP code. You want your action (in VR or not) to call the server. I suggest to :

1. make the send action work by just visiting the page
2. make sure it works without VR, for example using a simple HTML button [How to Call a PHP Function on the Click of a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button)
3. finally make it work with VR and A-Frame probably using the cursor and a bit of JavaScript https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/cursor.html#example

Comment: I am working with php and aframe first time. Can you give me an example? Then I can understand properly.

Comment: I have tried lot of times. But it does not work. It's not like normal html. I need to call with ajax. Can you please give an example? Then I can understand.

Comment: The first step will be to be able to host the PHP page, even if it's just a Hello world.