# How to using GoogleAPI access_token & refresh_token, for YoutubeAPI?

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-oauth

sorry before, maybe this is a stupid question.

I tried to make an application using Google Oauth2 using the steps from the tutorial:
https://medium.com/@pablo127/google-api-authentication-with-oauth-2-on-the-example-of-gmail-a103c897fd98

Currently I have succeeded until I get access_token and refresh_token as below:

```
{
  "access_token": "*****",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "*****",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

What I want to ask is, how to use the data on YoutubeAPI:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert

Q1: So that I can subscribe or unsubscribe to certain channels through my application.

Q2: Also, how can I use "refresh_token" to get the next "access_token".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Aaaand you've just posted your access token to the Internet...

Comment: LOL, thanks for remind me *__^

Comment: You need to get new tokens (not just edit the post).  Edit histories are saved on Stack Overflow, so I can still view your tokens here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53193901/revisions

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button that calls the [`subscriptionsInsert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert#usage) function. If you need information on how to create the button, you can refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button).

In the code provided, the channel that you subscribe to when the function is called is fixed to the channel with the ID: `UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw`. To change this, you can try using [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) to get the `channelId`.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&forUsername={USER_NAME}&part=id
```

As for your second question, you can [refresh an access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) if you requested offline access to the scopes associated with the token.

> - If you use a Google API Client Library, the [client object](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingclient) refreshes    the access token as needed as long as you configure that object for
>     offline access.
> - If you are not using a client library, you need to set the `access_type` HTTP query parameter to `offline` when [redirecting the user to Google's OAuth 2.0 server](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#redirecting). In that case, Google's authorization server returns a refresh token when you [exchange an authorization code](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code) for an access token. Then, if the access token expires (or at any other time), you can use a refresh token to obtain a new access token.

Comment: Sorry i am newbie for this, my question is how to implementation using PHP when i had "access token" using for "googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels" ?