# How to code Javascript to count up the number one by one using onclick function and php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, onclick

I'm doing the scoreboard website, so the CSS and HTML is already finished but I stuck with how to count up the score one by one. I use php to change the class name in div and the number will be change. Now I need to change value in the variables in php to change the number. I want to know how to write command to count up the value in php by onclick function, one by one. Thanks for your help.

This is script and php.

```
function myFunction(){
<?php
    $s = 1;
    $d = "display-no-$s";
?>  }
```

and this is HTML

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>   
    <div id="clock-container">
        <div id="display-1" class="display-container display-size-12 <?php echo $d; ?>">
            <div class="segment-x segment-a"><span class="segment-border"></span></div>
            <div class="segment-y segment-b"><span class="segment-border"></span></div>
            <div class="segment-y segment-c"><span class="segment-border"></span></div>
            <div class="segment-x segment-d"><span class="segment-border"></span></div>
            <div class="segment-y segment-e"><span class="segment-border"></span></div>
            <div class="segment-y segment-f"><span class="segment-border"></span></div>
            <div class="segment-x segment-g"><span class="segment-border"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because html/css/js runs in the browser (client side) you will need to create an http request  (forms, ajax, etc) to let php (server side) know about the changes to make. There a plenty of ways to do this so your question is a bit broad for a good answer. Try to learn about the differences of server and client side coding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: This link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button

Comment: you cant combine client and server side script