# php file's code not executing through ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a button in my PHP file, and when I click on that button, I want another PHP file to run and save some data in a MySQL table. For that I am using AJAX call as suggested at this link ([How to call a PHP function on the click of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button)) which is an answer from StackOverflow itself.

Here is my show_schedule file from which I am trying to execute code of another PHP file:

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
        var place_type = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(place_type);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "foursquare_api_call.php",
            data: { place_type: place_type }
        }).done(function( data ) {
            alert("foursquare api called");
            $('#userModal_2').modal('show');
        });
    });
```

here 'edit' is the class of the button and that button's id is being printed in the console correctly.

here is my foursquare_api_call.php file (which should be run when the button is clicked):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('connection.php');

    if(isset($_POST['place_type'])){
        $city = $_SESSION['city'];
        $s_id = $_SESSION['sid'];
        $query = $_POST['place_type'];
        echo "<script>console.log('inside if, before url')</script>";
        $url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&v=20180323&limit=10&near=$city&query=$query";
        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        echo "<script>console.log('inside if, after url')</script>";
        $obj = json_decode($json,true);
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($obj['response']['venues']);$i++){
            $name = $obj['response']['venues'][$i]['name'];
            $latitude = $obj['response']['venues'][$i]['location']['lat'];
            $longitude = $obj['response']['venues'][$i]['location']['lng'];
            $address = $obj['response']['venues'][$i]['location']['address'];

            if(isset($address)){
                $statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO temp (name, latitude, longitude, address) VALUES ($name, $latitude, $longitude, $address)");
                $result = $statement->execute();
            }
            else{
                $statement = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO temp (name, latitude, longitude) VALUES ($name, $latitude, $longitude)");
                $result = $statement->execute();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

none of the console.log is logged in the console and also the 'temp' table is not updated. Can anyone tell me where I am making mistake? Or is it even possible to execute the code of a PHP file like this?

Comment: did you check the networktab?

Comment: there is an entry for 'foursquare_api_call.php' file.

Comment: Well what is the response when u click it

Comment: it first displays the alert message and then the model is displayed.

Comment: but there are no entries in the 'temp' table.

Comment: btw `echo "<script>console.log...` is not how one should debug in php code

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is making an HTTP request to the URL that executes you PHP program.

When it gets a response, you do this:

> ```
>     .done(function( data ) {
>         alert("foursquare api called");
>         $('#userModal_2').modal('show');
>     }
> ```

So you:

1. Alert something
2. Show a model

At no point do you do anything with `data`, which is where the response has been put.

Just sending some HTML containing a script element to the browser doesn't cause it to turn that HTML into a DOM and execute all the script elements.

You'd need to do that explicitly.

---

That said, sending chunks of HTML with embedded JS back through Ajax is *messy* at best.

This is why most web services return data formatted as JSON and leave it up to the client-side JS to process that data.

Comment: OP says in a comment that there is no records added to the table, which is done on the PHP side.

Answer (score -1):

to return the contents of php code you can do something like this

you can use any call to this function

```
function check_foursquare_api_call(place_type) {
    var place_type= encodeURIComponent(place_type);
    var xhttp;
//last moment to check if the value exists and is of the correct type
    if (place_type== "") {
    document.getElementById("example_box").innerHTML = "missing or wrong place_type";
    return;
  } 
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("example_box").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      $('#userModal_2').modal('show');
    }
  };
 
    xhttp.open("GET", "foursquare_api_call.php?place_type="+place_type, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

this will allow you to send and execute the code of the foursquare_api_call file and return any elements to example_box, you can return the entire modal if you want,
you can use any POST / GET method, monitor the progress, see more here
[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)